# How to let espresso tests fail for a specific condition

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

For my espresso tests, I am searching for a way to let all tests fail before they run, if a specific condition is not met. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The condition I was mentioning is supposed to be something like the status of internet connection or anything similar. But the important point here is to prevent all tests from running if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a jUnit rule to handle that? Specifically the Verifier rule. https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules#verifier-rule

Verifier is a base class for Rules like ErrorCollector, which can turn 
otherwise passing test methods into failing tests if a verification check is failed.

```
private static String sequence;

public static class UsesVerifier {
  @Rule
  public final Verifier collector = new Verifier() {
    @Override
    protected void verify() {
      sequence += "verify ";
    }
  };

  @Test
  public void example() {
    sequence += "test ";
  }

  @Test
  public void verifierRunsAfterTest() {
    sequence = "";
    assertThat(testResult(UsesVerifier.class), isSuccessful());
    assertEquals("test verify ", sequence);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried System.exit(-1) or System.exit(0) ? One of these should serve your purpose depending on what condition you are trying to check. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)).